# Calculating Array Length from Array of Averages?

Tags: probability

I want to calculate The Array.Size() with only a small subset of information.

I am writing a program that analyses the results of unreadable code, which would tell the user the most probable Size of the array which is random length, and based on this Size, a calculation can be made about the probability of receiving an exact element in real-time.

---

There is an array which contains potentially 1-10000 elements, but the exact length of that array, or the total number of elements, Array.Size() is unknown each time.

Every few seconds there is a "roll", the roll() method picks and then displays 4 random elements from that array, for example:

re, to, ha, pi

I am now aware that at least these 4 elements exist within the array.

I decide to watch the element [ha]

The roll() method continues "rolling", which continues to select and then display 4 elements at random.

I count how many "rolls" it takes [ha] to appear again. And repeat/record that result 10 times.

12, 21, 48, 26, 12, 89, 32, 11, 42, 51

On average, it took 34.4 times for [ha] to appear again.

Then I select a new element [pi]

The roll() method continues "rolling", which continues to select and then display 4 elements at random.

I count how many "rolls" it takes [pi] to appear again. And record the results 10 times.

2, 6, 75, 53, 23, 12, 22, 12, 34, 11

On average, it took 25 times for [ha] to appear again.

---

One way to solve this would be noting each new value that appears. although this would be time intensive. I could accurately discover all Elements eventually - and then simply count them. I am attempting to do this in far less time with far less roll()'s

Comment: Looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: You didn't put any language/platform,so here is python code http://isaacslavitt.com/2015/12/19/german-tank-problem-with-pymc-and-pystan/